# How to replace the Segoe UI Emoji font in an UWP app?

Tags: c#, fonts, uwp

I'd like to replace the `Segoe UI Emoji` font with a newer version for all text controls in my app on older Windows 10 devices, so all devices support all the new Unicode 11 Emoji.
Is there a way to do this in an UWP C# Windows 10 app?

I tried declaring my own FontFamily and replacing `ContentControlThemeFontFamily` but it does not work. It only updates the actual font characters like `ABCD...`.
Example:

```
TextBlock FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/seguiemj.ttf#Segoe UI Emoji" Text=""/>
```

The  Emoji is part of Unicode 11 and shows up on all updated W10 devices, but like mentioned above not on older devices (only shows as empty square).
All of this even through I set my own font that should support it (copied from an updated W10 PC).

Comment: Could you share more about your custom `FontFamily`? And we often use this  `<FontFamily x:Key="SymbolThemeFontFamily">Segoe MDL2 Assets</FontFamily>` and set text control font family property `<TextBox FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"/>`.

Comment: Updated my question. Sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following into the `App.xaml` which fixed my problem:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/seguiemj.ttf#Segoe UI Emoji,XamlAutoFontFamily</FontFamily>
```